# allready have search filter table js code - works fine, simply would like to have highlighed text result. any ideas anyone?

Tags: javascript, html, highlight

## HTML

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" 
       placeholder="Search Titles">
    *</p>

<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
window.onload = function() {
   var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

   for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     rows[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
}

function ContactsearchFX() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";

      }
    }
  }

   var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

   if (input.value.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Have trawled the web with no result. New to js so any help would be very appreciated.
Is the a simple way of adding a few lines of code?
Would be great.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. Every row that does not meet the search criteria is hidden. Do you want to highlight every remaining row then?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what would be great is if just the actual text match in a specified column but on all the rows of that column.
If that makes any sense.

Comment: See how this search is highlighted - https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/hdyLpy37/ - would like same effect on the text search results in my table. not sure if I could regex code?